# HipHop PHP - Issues with string concat

Tags: php, string, memory-management, concatenation, hiphop

I'm having serious issues with string concatenation in HipHop->C++ compiled PHP scripts.

My scripts rely heavily on concatenating strings, it performs in 0.6 seconds with PHP and 60 seconds compiled with HipHop. That's almost a 10,000% difference!

Appears to be a problem with dynamic memory allocation, according to [this article](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/04/04/hiphop-for-php-benchmark-revenge-of-php/):

> They prove our suspicions. Source code compilation brings major side
>   effect known from other compiled languages ​​such as C, C++ or C#:
>   slow string operations, and the need for StringBuilder functionality!.

HipHop compiled scripts are considerably faster in all other areas, giving a speed and memory improvement of around 50%, which is something important to my project.

My question is: what kind of trick could I pull (in PHP code) to force the HipHop compiled PHP scripts to pre-allocate the memory needed, or whatever, to stop this obscure dynamic memory allocation which causes intense slowdown. Or is there another clever little way of concatenating strings, or some kind of string-builder implementation?

Comment: I tested '$a='';for($i=0;$i<50000;$i++)$a="test".$a."test";' code and HipHop runs ten times faster then PHP. Are you sure that you run compiled programm and not HipHop on-the-fly compilation? Please show us your code and how you run HipHop.

Comment: Certain, I'll get some code segment for you.

Comment: I compile like this: `hphp script.php --program=AppName -t cpp -f exe -o AppName`

Comment: When I separate a short code segment it works fine... but as part of my 1,000 line script and it is slow. I record the `microtime` before and after everything, and it is most certainly due to multiple string concats. But then separating this into a new script does not have the problem. So something is going wrong somewhere, but it's not in my PHP code.

Comment: Well, as you can see string concatenations works really fast. Please localize your problem or post complete code somewhere (ideone.com for example) or ... well remove this question as no one can help with something this vague :)

Comment: Results with your script: PHP=1.25 seconds, HipHop=0.85 seconds. It does seem to occur only as part of my larger script.

Comment: OK. I will try to find out exactly what is going on and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

HPHPc has been deprecated. Try using HHVM https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php